# Gruntjs read from external json file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am attempting to read in an external json file and use that in a custom task:

Inside `initConfig`

```
grunt.initConfig({
  env: grunt.file.readJSON("PATH"),
  ...
  ..
  .
});

// Registering a task
grunt.registerTask('Namehere', 'DescriptionHere', function () { 
  // HOW DO I GET AT THE "env" 

  "<%= env.environment %>" // Doesnt work just gives me the string literal "<%= environmentVars.environment %>"
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely to use `grunt.config.get("env")` or `grunt.config("env")` for this purpose.

More info: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#grunt.config.get (thanks @Mike Fielden)